# How can I view other people's calendar in Microsoft Outlook for Android?

Tags: outlook

How can I view other people's calendar in Microsoft Outlook for Android?

On Outlook for Microsoft Windows, I can view other people's calendars when creating a new meeting:

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: I am still interested if someone has any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheduling assistant on Outlook for Android works differently than the one for Windows.

In Outlook, click on the calendar --> new event, enter the people who should attend the meeting.

[image: IMG:]

Select the date, then time of the meeting.

[image: IMG:]

The attendees are listed on the bottom with green checked marked when they are free, red when they are not free.
The chosen time for the meeting will also be green or red whether it is free or overlapping with other meetings.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Clicking on an attendee will show either the person is free, busy or tentative.

Comment: Thanks, picking a time and looking at whether all invitees are available isn't efficient

Comment: Agree. Unfortunately that how Microsoft has implemented it for now